What is this usage of 出た?

恋人とかいるんすか?


俺は仕事が恋人なんでね


出た昭和ぎゃぐ

What does 出た here mean? As far I can see the sentence is akin...
"Do you have a girlfriend?" "My job is my lover" "A showa era joke"?

You interpreted the sentences correctly in general. Here, I'd translate "出た昭和ぎゃぐ" as

Here we go again with the showa era joke


Yet another showa era joke


To explain the meaning and use-cases of "出た" comprehensively would be out of scope here, so let's simply interpret 出た as "(it) came", and remember that if you want to tease what another person just said, it's typical in Japanese to use "出た".

Here's a dad joke. I know it's the funniest one you've ever seen thanks, but let's pretend it's not that funny.

カレーはカレーでも食べられないカレーは？カレーンダーでした！

What's a curry that you can't eat? A currynder (calendar!)
You may say

出たよ、親父ギャグ
出た、親父ギャグ
でたでた、親父ギャグ
また出た、親父ギャグ
出た (if you don't really need to explain what you're referring to)

You would not use it when you are genuinely offended by my joke.
You would use it when my joke was

cliche
lame
causes eye-rolling

If you knew in advance that such 昭和ギャグ would be coming, you may say

出るぞ、昭和ギャグ
来るぞ、昭和ギャグ

This would mean "lame showa-era joke coming up".
